# is my nested for is not working? value won't be copied (VBA, Looping, Using a nested for to copy data)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, nested-loops

hi can you help me solve my problem? my problem is I want to copy some data from another worksheet with some condition, i'm using the nested for to do the looping if the condition is met.

but the problem is the value that I want to copy is not copied to the destination cell, its blank.
but the rest of the code is working and the data is successfully copied.

do you know how to solve this? did i miss some syntax ? thank you so much!

```
lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'b value is more than 30.000 data
b = wsDestI.Cells(wsDestI.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lCopyLastRow
If IsEmpty(wsCopy.Range("E" & 9 + i).Value) = True Then
    'this nested for is not working, it wont copy the data
    For s = 4 To b
        If (wsCopy.Range("B" & 9 + i).Value = wsDestI.Range("G" & s).Value) Then
            wsDestI.Range("C" & s).copy wsDest.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsDestI.Range("G" & s).copy wsDest.Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsDestI.Range("M" & s).copy wsDest.Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next s
ElseIf IsEmpty(wsCopy.Range("B" & 9 + i).Value) = True Then
        wsCopy.Range("E" & i + 9).copy wsDest.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        wsCopy.Range("K" & 9 + i).copy wsDest.Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        wsDest.Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "0"
Else:
wsCopy.Activate
wsDest.Activate
wsCopy.Range("E" & 9 + i).copy wsDest.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
wsCopy.Range("B" & 9 + i).copy wsDest.Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
wsCopy.Range("K" & 9 + i).copy wsDest.Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End If
Next i
```

Comment: This idea ` wsDest.Range("P" & Rows.Count).` is probably not the nest option, if they are all to be on the same row, I'd use `b`, but you need to reset `b` in each iteration of the lop

Comment: It's not clear which block works and which one doesn't... can you [edit] your question to only include the relevant code? Also, that nested `For s` loop might not be doing what you think it's doing - have you tried setting a breakpoint (F9) on the `If IsEmpty` line, running your code, and then stepping through (F8) line by line to make sure it's doing exactly what it should be doing? While debugging, keep an eye on the *locals* toolwindow and see whether `s` and `i` have the expected values and that the source & destination ranges are what they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try - I've cleaned up some of your syntax and I fully qualified all of the `Rows.Count`s. I also did some additional things like removed those `Activate` lines (unnecessary), changed your `i` loop to start at 10 (since you just add 9 to it everywhere anyways), and added all the declarations/sets that you weren't displaying in your post.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long, b As Long, i As Long, s As Long
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDestI As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wsCopy")
    Set wsDestI = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wsDestI")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wsDest")

    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    b = wsDestI.Cells(wsDestI.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 10 To lCopyLastRow

        If IsEmpty(wsCopy.Range("E" & i).Value) = True Then

            For s = 4 To b

                If (wsCopy.Range("B" & i).Value = wsDestI.Range("G" & s).Value) Then
                    wsDestI.Range("C" & s).Copy wsDest.Range("M" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    wsDestI.Range("G" & s).Copy wsDest.Range("S" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    wsDestI.Range("M" & s).Copy wsDest.Range("P" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If

            Next s

        ElseIf IsEmpty(wsCopy.Range("B" & i).Value) = True Then

            wsCopy.Range("E" & 9 + i).Copy wsDest.Range("M" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsCopy.Range("K" & 9 + i).Copy wsDest.Range("P" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsDest.Range("S" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = 0

        Else

            wsCopy.Range("E" & i).Copy wsDest.Range("M" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsCopy.Range("B" & i).Copy wsDest.Range("S" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsCopy.Range("K" & i).Copy wsDest.Range("P" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: actually I edit it because the process in cell B starting from cell B10 until the last cell that have value, and I think if I change it to 10 the program doesn't work because if the filed cell only 2 cell it will error because 10 is greater than 2.

Comment: @higamsaiful Then you would need something like `If lCopyLastRow < 10 Then Exit Sub` to prevent that.